# add rows on click reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint

I have written one component Employee in this component i am showing employee list in table format. In this table format i have giving a column of edit, which renders another component Permissions. I want to show this component just below to that corresponding row (I believe which means to render the component in the next row just below to that corresponding row which was selected). I have done something like this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <ul>
         <li className="u-name" key={emp.empId}>
            {enableempDetails ? (
            <Link to={"/empdata/" + emp.empId}>
            {emp.empName}
            </Link>
            ) : (
            <span>{emp.empName}</span>
            )}
         </li>
      </ul>
   </td>
   <td>
      <ul>
         <li>{emp.status}</li>
      </ul>
   </td>
   {this.props.permissionView && this.props.app != "undefined" ? (
   <td>
      <a
         href="javascript:void(0)"
         onClick={e => {
      this.showRolesForm(e, emp.empId);
      }}>
      <i className="fa fa-edit" />
      </a>
      {this.state.rolePermission && (
      <Permissions
         empId={emp.empId}
         empType={"EMP"}
         />
      )}
   </td>
   ) : null}
   {this.props.emp.accountType == "SERVICE" ? (
   <td className="action-div">{downloadButton}</td>
   ) : null}
   <td className="action-div">{deleteButton}</td>
</tr>
```

Permissions component is coming below to that corresponding row but not in entire new row, it is rendered just in the new . How to render this Permissions component in entire new row of table.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the Permission component in a new `<tr>` tag. However, since the return statement can only accept one child, you need to wrap the two pair of `<tr>` tags with a `<React.Fragment>`, like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li className="u-name" key={emp.empId}>
                    {enableempDetails ? (
                        <Link to={"/empdata/" + emp.empId}>
                            {emp.empName}
                        </Link>
                    ) : (
                            <span>{emp.empName}</span>
                        )}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>{emp.status}</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        {this.props.permissionView && this.props.app != "undefined" ? (
            <td>
                <a
                    href="javascript:void(0)"
                    onClick={e => {
                        this.showRolesForm(e, emp.empId);
                    }}>
                    <i className="fa fa-edit" />
                </a>

            </td>
        ) : null}
        {this.props.emp.accountType == "SERVICE" ? (
            <td className="action-div">{downloadButton}</td>
        ) : null}
        <td className="action-div">{deleteButton}</td>
    </tr>
    {this.props.permissionView
    && this.props.app != "undefined"
    && this.state.rolePermission
    && (<tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <Permissions
                    empId={emp.empId}
                    empType={"EMP"}
                />
            </td>
        </tr>)}
</React.Fragment>
```

The two empty `<td>` tags are used to vertically align the `Permission` component with the edit button, you can remove them if that's not what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will try this

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right, I forgot about the colSpan attribute. I think my approach will adds a table row, while yours will add a column. But thanks for the reminder that we can make the element span more than 1 row by using the rowSpan attribute.